# Can't fetch table values based on reference id of another table in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables like `keyboard_countries`, `keyboard_languages` and `lang_regions`. `lang_regions` contains the reference ids of `keyboard_countries` and `keyboard_languages`.

Schema for these tables are as follows:

```
create_table "keyboard_countries", force: true do |t|
t.string   "cc"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "keyboard_languages", force: true do |t|
t.string   "ln"
t.string   "lc"
t.string   "lr"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end 

create_table "lang_regions", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "keyboardCountry_id"
t.integer  "keyboardLanguages_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end



add_index "lang_regions", ["keyboardCountry_id"], 
name: "index_lang_regions_on_keyboardCountry_id", 
using: :btree add_index "lang_regions", 
["keyboardLanguages_id"], 
name: "index_lang_regions_on_keyboardLanguages_id", 
using: :btree
```

The query for fetching data that I have tried was: `select keyboardCountry_id from lang_regions;`

But I couldn't fetch data from `lang_regions` with the `keyboardCountry_id`:

The error was: `column "keyboardlanguages_id" does not exist in lang_regions table`.

Can anyone help me for finding a solution for this issue.

Comment: What was the exact query you tried to fetch your data with? If you could post that in your question, you would help us to see where things might be wrong. Also, in your schema you have a camelCased `keyboardLanguages_id`, if you wish to fetch data from a table with camelCasing, you need to surround that camelCased column with double quotes in your query.

Comment: Then there is your problem, the query should be `select "keyboardCountry_id" from lang_regions;`, not `select keyboardCountry_id from lang_regions;`. Notice the double quotes surrounding the `keyboardCountry_id` indentifier in the former query. PostgreSQL folds the casing to all lowercase (SQL spec compliant) if you do not double quote your identifiers.

Comment: You are welcome. I'll post this as an answer though it is been said before on SO.

Comment: But when I tried a group  by query like 'select * from lang_regions group by "keyboardCountry_id";' I got an error as follows 'column "lang_regions.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function'. Do you know why?

Comment: This is a different issue, you need to explicitly name the columns you wish to use in your `GROUP BY` in your `SELECT`, not rely on the expansion of the `*`. Thus: 'select "keyboardCountry_id" from lang_regions group by "keyboardCountry_id";' should do the trick.

Comment: So I can only select the field that is given in group by clause. I need to work with this query 'select "keyboardCountry_id","keyboardLanguages_id" from lang_regions group by "keyboardCountry_id";'

Comment: Yes, all *non aggregated* columns have to be explicitly stated in the `GROUP BY`/`SELECT`, otherwise there is ambiguity and PostgreSQL does not know what you mean (PostgreSQL never guesses, it always asks). If you only wish to sort by `"keyboardCountry_id"`, you could put a `DISTINCT` aggregation on there as well: `SELECT DISTINCT("keyboardCountry_id"),"keyboardLanguages_id" FROM lang_regions;` and cut out the `GROUP BY` entirely.

Comment: You are very welcome...happy PostgreSQL-ing ;)

Answer (score 1):

As found in my comments on the question:

If you use identifiers (column names in your case) with all UPPERCASE characters or camelCasing you will have to double quote them in your queries to preserve the case sensitivity. If you do not double quote your identifiers, they will be folded to all lower case. Why? Because the SQL specification dictates it and PostgreSQL tries to adhere to it as much as possible.

Thus your original query:

```
select keyboardCountry_id from lang_regions;
```

Should become:

```
select "keyboardCountry_id" from lang_regions;
```

Another, more scalable approach might be to drop this camelCasing all together and rename your columns to be all lowercase. These will make for easier-to-read queries and avoids this pitfall all together (and makes your queries more SQL spec compliant).